# Line Counting Program in C

Tags: c

I am learning C language from a book called "The C Programming Language" by Brian Kernighan & Dennis Ritchie and have been stuck at its basic lesson of line counting program. The program runs but it does not give an output of how many lines were inputed.

Have given the program code below, please help on the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int c, nl;
    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF )
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d \n", nl);

    return 0;
}
```

The code should read the input and then output how many lines of text were given. How should this be changed to make it work?

Comment: You should work on your indentation, and possibly use more braces too. Also, how did you run it, what input did you provide, and what output did you get?

Comment: Show the actual code. From  where you are reading it ?

Comment: `int main(void)`. How well did you follow that lesson?

Comment: And also : What did you expect? What did you do? What did you have? How is that different from what you expected? What have you tried to understand your problem?

Comment: How are you opening the file? Or is this all of your code?

Comment: Works fine for me. A couple of points: 1. main should be declared `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. 2. `return 0;` at the end of main.  3. If the last line doesn't end with `\n` it isn't counted.

Comment: input `EOF`(ctrl+z or ctrl+d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no issue with code; it work's fine, only the issue- it was taking input and was not giving output.

In windows to end input, 
we have to press Ctrl + Z followed by Enter key, it will show the count of lines in input.

Answer (score 4):

Your program works fine.  However, I would prefix main with the int type to keep the compiler quiet.  It should look like this:

int main(void)

When you call it, what I did was this:

```
$$$ ->./test6 < test4.c
19
$$$ ->wc test4.c
      19      48     379 test4.c
$$$ ->
```

The getchar function is the same thing as getc(stdin), so when you run your program, it takes it's input from stdin (keyboard) or a file redirected to stdin.

EDIT: As someone pointed out, if the last line doesn't have a \n terminator, that line will not be counted.  So I rewrote your code to account for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;  /* Character */
    int cp; /* Previous Character */
    int n;  /* Number of lines */

    n = 0;
    c = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        cp = c;
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            n++;
            continue;
        }
        if (c == EOF && cp == '\n') break;
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            n++;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in the code, I used fall-though logic to either continue the loop or to break out of it.  Now I tested this code using clang on FreeBSD and it works properly.

The logic of this program is as follows:

1. Save current character as the previous character.
2. Get the next character and make it the current character.
3. Check the current character to see if it's a newline character.
4. If it is, then we increment the line counter and restart the loop.
5. Check the current character to see if it's EOF and the previous character to see if it's the newline character.
6. If it is, then break out of the loop.
7. Check the current character to see if it's EOF.
8. If it is, then increment the line counter and break out of the loop.

That is how you deal with the final line not being terminated by a newline character and still have it counted as a line.  Note that this is considered a special case and needs to be explicitly coded for.  If you continue into the software development profession, then you will encounter special case situations a lot and you need to code the handling for each one that you encounter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working properly.I checked it in Ubuntu.

Just press Ctrl+d if you are working in Linux to end the input.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am working in Windows environment